# Running external program

Tags: interoperability, external-calls

I am trying to run gnuplot and send it some plotting commands from Mathematica. Unfortunately without any luck. For me the documentation is completely useless as it gives little to no practical examples.
My attempts look like this:

```
RunThrough["gnuplot", "set term png\n set out \"test.png\"\n test"]
```

Now this produces no output in Mathematica and neither the test file is produced. So I tried

```
<< "!echo $TERM"
```

which is in documentation [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ExternalPrograms.html). This again produces nothing and by nothing I mean absolutely no output:

[image]

Finally I tried

```
RunProcess["date"]
```

as in [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RunProcess.html) and it returned:
[image].

as expected however the very first execution took almost 10 seconds.

However, I would really like to use `RunThrough` and I have no idea why it is not doing at least what is described in the documentation. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?
(MA 11.1.0 on Debian 9.2).

Comment: The specifics of external calls may depend on your OS. What's yours? Also take care using << as it will evaluate what it gets back from the external call. On my Windows PC << "!echo 1+1" yields 2.

Comment: Have you tried `RunProcess` more than once? Is it slow on second try as well? I could imagine that it is not. If it is not as slow as you report (which is not the case for me) I think it would be the best choice for what you want. `RunThrough` "reads the output of the program as Wolfram Language Input" which is almost certainly not what you want. If `` then I would use `Import` as indicated by Henrik...

Answer (score 5):

This works for me under Linux:

```
gpcmds = "set term png\nset out \"test.png\"\ntest\nexit";
RunProcess["gnuplot", All, gpcmds]
```

The documentation for `RunThrough` says that it passes the `InputForm` of its second argument to the program.  The input form of a string has double quotes, so `RunThrough` passes the double quotes to `gnuplot`, which is not what we want.  As evidence of this behavior, consider writing the output of `gnuplot` to a file (named `tmp999.txt` in this example) like this

```
RunThrough["gnuplot > tmp999.txt 2>&1", "print \"1 + 1\""]
```

The "2>&1" is important, since `gnuplot` writes to unit 2.  We hope to get back "1 + 1" from `gnuplot`, so MMA can evaluate it, but instead we get this error message (in our tmp999.txt file) from `gnuplot` complaining about the double quotes:

```
RunProcess[{"cat", "tmp999.txt"}]
(*
    <|ExitCode -> 0, StandardOutput -> 
      gnuplot> "print \"1 + 1\"\n"
               ^
               line 0: invalid command

      , StandardError -> |>
    *)
```

The lesson seems to be, do not use `RunThrough` for `gnuplot`, unless we can find a way to not pass those double quotes to `gnuplot`.

Answer (score 2):

On macos, I made good experiences by calling command line tools by `Import`; virtually all other methods don't work for me (well, they did not when I tried the last time). Here an example

```
Import["! date", "Text"]
```

> "Sat Nov 11 17:49:02 CET 2017"

If the process generates large tables, then `"Table"` instead of `"Text"` is a better alternative.

Well, that did also not always help. Once a collegue, a real bash connaisseur, explained me why the shell that Mathematica uses does not call my `/.profile` and so does not know my path variables. He taught me that either

I have to use the full path to the program to run or

I have to force Mathematica's shell to load my `.profile` with

```
Import[StringJoin["! source ", 
  FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, ".profile "}], " && ", 
  programstring], "Text"]
```

where `programstring` constains the command as you would type it into the command line.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `2>&1` redirects stderr to stdout, which will `Import` catch error messages along with the standard output (if you want that). The trailing `&` runs the program in background, which doesn't really make sense (or a difference) here AFAIK.

Comment: @AlbertRetey Good point. I removed it.